# powershell substring of azure_AppService.2.4.0-alpha.1145.nupkg to get only 2.4.0-alpha.1145

Tags: powershell

I want to get just the version number of the nupkg file and assign it to variable.
I want to get everything between the first dot and the last dot (before the bupkg) file as the version

```
Example - 

azure_AppService.2.4.0-alpha.1145.nupkg to get only 2.4.0-alpha.1145

I tried below but doesnt seem to work
$test="azure_AppService.2.4.0-alpha.1145.nupkg"
$ver=$test.IndexOf(".")
$test.Substring($ver+1)
2.4.0-alpha.1145.nupkg
$verstring=$test.Substring($ver+1)
$ve=$verstring.Split(".nupkg")[0]
$ve
2
$verstring.Split('nupkg')[0]
2.4.0-al
$verstring.Split('.nupkg')[0]
2
$verstring.Split(".nupkg")[0]
2
$verstring.Split("nupkg")[0]
2.4.0-al
```

Comment: [regex]::Matches($test, '\.(.*?).nupkg').Groups[1].Value